New M4 Max - watching videos on an external disk has occasional video and sound freezes (old Intel i9 didn't have the same issue with the same setup)
I am surprised this is happening on my new M4 Max, especially when it didn't happen on my old 2019 Intel i9! I literally switched the old out for the new, so it's the exact same disk and setup (aside from the OS version on the MBP): MBP <-> CalDigit TS3 Plus <-> USB 3.1 Seagate HDD connected on one of the 10Gbs USB-C ports.
Is there anything I can do to determine why it's happening and fix it?
Thanks!

What other programs are running?

Plenty of other programs (the same was true on the i9). I'll try shutting them all down and see if that makes a difference next time. For what it's worth, the issue doesn't occur watching a video that is on the internal disk with all the programs running. Thanks!

First I'd test whether you get the problem without the hub in the middle -- connect the drive directly to the Mac. Then I'd test/verify the hard drive. It could be that the drive is starting to fail, coincidentally at the time you got the new Mac.
